# Range of cells in a row being editable/not editable based on an adjacent cell value

Tags: excel, vba

What I require:

- When the text Yes is entered into eg A2, I would like B2:E2 to become not able to be edited, but the range A3:E7 still editable.
- When the text Yes is entered into eg A3, I would like B3:E3 to become not to be edited, in addition to B2:E2 (the row above) not being able to be edited.
- The above functionality will continue for approx 100 rows on the sheet.
- When the text Yes is removed from a cell eg A2, then only B2:E2 become editable again.  When Yes is entered back into the cell they become not able to be edited again.
- If cells in the A column are blank, the corresponding columns B:E for that row are editable.

Current State in the image attached:
Cells A2:E7 are unlocked, all other cells in the sheet remain locked
The remainder of the sheet is protected without a password/select unlocked cells only (but could contain a password if required)

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Code below has to be entered in a Worksheet object, under VBA project properties. I have tested the code and it seems to be working. Please report if any problem comes up. If you want to extend the range on which the code works, simply edit currSheet.Range("A2") to currSheet.Range("A100") etc.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim currSheet As Worksheet
Set currSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'declare source range - can be a cell, a range of cells, entire column, entirerow etc.
Dim sourceCell As Range
Set sourceCell = currSheet.Range("A2")
'declare range that will be locked/unlocked
Dim tarRange As Range
Set tarRange = currSheet.Range("B2:E2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
currSheet.Unprotect
If Target = sourceCell Then
    set_cellLockStatus sourceCell, "Yes", tarRange, True
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
currSheet.Protect
End Sub

Public Sub set_cellLockStatus(source_rng As Range, sourceValueCondition As Variant, target_rng As Range, lockCell As Boolean)
'take source range, check if source condition is met - if yes, lock or unlock target range
source_rng.Locked = False
    With source_rng
        If source_rng.Value2 = sourceValueCondition Then
            target_rng.Locked = lockCell
            target_rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Else:
            target_rng.Locked = Not lockCell
            target_rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.  I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Code in Worksheet - Change event :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then                   ' column A changed
        ThisRow = Target.Row                    'get row number
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect  'unprotect sheet
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Locked = True
            Range("C" & ThisRow).Locked = True
            Range("D" & ThisRow).Locked = True
            Range("E" & ThisRow).Locked = True
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Protect    'protect sheeet
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            Range("B" & ThisRow).Locked = False
            Range("C" & ThisRow).Locked = False
            Range("D" & ThisRow).Locked = False
            Range("E" & ThisRow).Locked = False
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Protect
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.  I will try this